# Removing windows partition didn't completely uninstall Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

I had deleted my windows partitions completely. But even after that, there was the windows boot entry displayed in BIOS (UEFI). When I tried to boot into that boot entry, it showed the message that the windows installed was damaged. Then, I installed windows again. Each time on booting, there were two entries, one showing the error and another one which booted me into the windows I just installed. There was also another folder windows.old in the C drive. I removed that folder using the disk cleanup option. But each time I boot, the two options are still being displayed. What had happened and how can I remove the other boot option?

Comment: you probably didn't delete EFI Partition along with Recovery Partition when you deleted C partition , these are hidden partitions and you will see them in Disk Management. If you need  to delete windows completely, you will need to delete these partitions a long with C partition. and then reinstall windows again which will recreate these partitions again.

Comment: Hey I did delete all the partitions except one which had Linux in it

Answer (score 0):

The entries in your UEFI BIOS are independent of the partitions on your drives.

If you want the errant entry removed, you would do so through the UEFI BIOS settings. Nothing you do on the drive will change that.

Windows will often fix this during setup, but in your case, it appears to have been orphaned and you'll need to remove it yourself.

You didn't specify exact make and model of your computer, so you'll have to refer to the owner's manual or do further research to determine what exact steps to take to remove the entry from the UEFI BIOS.

Comment: It has always been my understanding that the entries are determined by the EFI partition on the drive, this is evident by the fact operating systems located on a drive will be missing, when the drive with the associated EFI partition is removed from the system.  As for the orphaned options that can be solved by rebuilding the Boot Configuration Data (BCD).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a helpful sequence of instructions from the folks at Laptop Magazine: https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/fix-0xc0000034-error-windows-10. Explains how to rebuild the BCD for a Win10 PC.

Comment: Author never mentioned a boot configuration data corruption, I actually did, but beyond that link-only answers are not helpful.